# Can't insert value into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code, but it doesn't insert the value of $_SESSION['steamid'], as intended. Everything above the `if` statement appears to work, because if I put something else (a test line) inside the `if` statement, it executes.

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_passwd, $db_dbase);
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
      mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `users`(`steamid`) VALUES (".$_SESSION['steamid'].")");
}
```

Comment: try to get the error caused by your queries

Comment: There are no errors at all.

Comment: just add quotation to your values like this **values ('".$_SESSION['steamid']."')**

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou Still doesn't work :(

Comment: please add this **echo mysqli_error($link);** after the last query and inside the if

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98450/discussion-between-alaa-m-jaddou-and-irqize).

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this, please post a code sample which is minimal but complete enough to execute (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 1):

You miss quote for the value, I think :

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_passwd, $db_dbase); 
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."'"); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) { 
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `users`(`steamid`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['steamid']."')"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your users table most likely contains many more REQUIRED fields then steamid.

Run your query manually on your db, the response will tell you that some fields are missing.

Just inserting the steamid like that doesn't really make sense.
I'm guessing you'd want to do something like this.

```
$steamid = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['steamid']);
mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT INTO users (userid, steamid, <other required fields>) VALUES ("'.$userid.'", "'.$steamid.'", <other required fields>);"
```

Always escape your values, leaving things open for sql injection will create many bugs.

Comment: I ran it with phpmyadmin with static value and the query passed well.

Comment: Was the code above an exact copy of your code?, because you're missing quotes around your value: "INSERT INTO `users`(`steamid`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['steamid']."')". for the column names you don't need to quote it, but for the values you do. + make sure to use the mysqli_real_escape_string function for your values.